# iOS today pulldown usage

Tags: ios

I'm trying to find out how much usage the iOS today pulldown gets, I have a hypothesis that non-advanced users may only accidentally pull it down, but don't know how to configure it and make it useful for them,
are there any stats or data that show how often the pulldown actually gets used instead of just being accidentally pulled down?

Comment: Just FYI I believe this feature is called the [Notification Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notification_Center), might help for research.

Comment: Thanks, had a look using that as well as Today View, not much luck.